# WordPress admin lost some admin privileges

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, privileges

On my WordPress site, the admin account has lost some admin privileges.
Like I can't add new plugins and themes, there's no menu for this.
And I can't update core WordPress. It says,

> WordPress 4.8 is available! Please notify the site administrator.

So How Can I get back my site administrator power?

Please see this image  -

[image: Can't add plugins]
![two muppets][1]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The site administrator would be the account that you used to create Wordpress in the first place, so the installation. If you did lose that account you should either try forgot password or edit it from the database. Do keep in mind that the Password in Wordpress is encrypted with a key that is needed. So you'll have to generate a new one on a page like: [link](http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4)

Comment: Hi

I have installed this wordpress with the current admin account. You  can see it, this is from phpmyadmin http://i.imgur.com/0h7Ozah.png

Comment: Weird, then do check the user_meta table and check the linked user_ID. It should be the ID correspondig to your account, if it isn't then thats the problem. Otherwise try uploading throught FTP and if that works you could always update manually and install plugins manually